# My animations/images won't render

Tags: rendering, animation, image

[image: This is what I get every time]

I'm new and need help. When I try to render an animation or image, this screen is all I get. I've followed a bunch of other posts on how to fix it and nothing, I'm using Cycles Render.
I don't know what other info to add, I've never done this and it's as simple as my animations won't render and pause like that in the picture every time. That's all I know, this is my first animation ever and I don't know what I did.
[image]

Comment: This will most definately need more information. Upload your blend to [blend exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). Then [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) your question and add the link from blendexchange.

Comment: This gets asked quite often. Please use the search box at the top. Also look through the many causes of blank rendering here: [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up) and here: [Render result is completely blank?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank)

Comment: I added the blender file.

Comment: on frame 1 your camera is aiming down where there is nothing  to see...https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeiaW.png

Comment: Well, I know that; it's part of the animation but my issue is that it won't render at all, that image I added to the question above is how it stayed for 12 hours.

Comment: You are rendering with lots of samples (16384 to be precise) that will take a while... maybe you misunderstood what square samples means. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64003/it-wont-render-stuck-on-the-1st-4-tiles-played-with-resolution-sample-size-a/64008#64008

Comment: Could you give me instructions on how to fix all of this? How many samples do you recommend?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24346/what-settings-affect-the-final-number-of-samples-in-cycles

Comment: same results, is there a way to restore my settings to default to maybe fix this?

Comment: I selected all objects and restored everything and repasted it. my issue is resolved, thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

You are using lots of samples(16384 for diffuse to be precise).

When using Branched Path Tracing the number of samples for each light path is multiplied by the AA samples.

If you enable square samples then that number gets multiplied by itself (square is not the shape of the samples but the number is squared).

[image]

Bring down the number of samples to a realistic figure, one that you can render in your system within your lifetime.